# How to build hadoop 2.7.1 plugins for eclipse

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I want to build hadoop eclipse plugin for hadoop 2.7.1 version. So how to build this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the hadoop eclipse plugin is very very old and unmaintained. Some time ago I tried to use it with hadoop 2.3 and even I was able to install it, it never worked. I don't recommend you waste your time with old plugins.